# How to convert GMT?

Tags: java

I trying to get data from database like..

```
       while(rs.next())
               {
                java.sql.Timestamp t=rs.getTimestamp("date");

                }
```

Now i want to convert Timestamp 't' into java.util.Date type.
In that i'm trying

```
Date d=new Date(t);//but hear given error
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(d.toGMTString());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? »Please give the code« is not a good start, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) already extends [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), so you don't need to do anything:

```
Date date = t;
```

You should read the docs for `Timestamp` for details of some potentially-unexpected behaviour though, in particular:

> Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date. The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

(I translate this as "Oops, we used inheritance where we should have used composition.")

To get around this, you may want to use:

```
Date date = new Date(t.getTime());
```

Comment: @user1557627 you must accept this answer, since it solved your issue